# Why are minima of $(k \bmod 4)$-Prime $\zeta$ functions $|P_x(r,t)|$ more frequent for $\frac\pi2\leq t \leq \pi$?

Tags: zeta-functions, prime-numbers

I got these plots when I evaluate the sum of truncated $(k \bmod 4)$-Prime $\zeta$ function, i.e.
$$
P_x(r,t)=P_{x;4,1}(-ir\cos t)+P_{x;4,3}(-ir\sin t)=\sum_{x\geq p\;\bmod\;4=3} p^{-ir\cos t}+\sum_{x\geq p\;\bmod\; 4=1} p^{-ir\sin t}.
$$
To be precise the plots below ($r$ up, $t$ to the right) show $\displaystyle\log\left(\frac{|P_x(r,t)|}{\pi(x)}\right)$:

$\hskip0.6in$ [image] 
[$\phantom{\Huge|}$ [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT4US.jpg) 
[$\phantom{\Huge|}$[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4qkU.jpg) 
[$\phantom{\Huge|}$[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWuyi.jpg) 
[$\phantom{\Huge|}$[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5QSo.jpg) 
$\hskip0.3in$$\scriptstyle \text{$r$ is plotted horizontal, $t$ vertical. Check the tooltips of the images for some infos and click to enlarge them.
}$

Since I got the impression that the red spots appear more often, when the race between $4m\pm 1$ primes is tied, I preferred to use values from [OEIS/A007351](http://oeis.org/A007351). I used the list of first 50 million primes from [here](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/).

> Why are low values of $|P_x(r,t)|$ more frequent on the right hand side $\left(\frac\pi2\leq t \leq \pi\right)$?

The last two plots also use two equally large sets of primes, but the prime race is not tied there. It would be better to write them as $P_{x;4,1}(-ir\cos t)+P_{y;4,3}(-ir\sin t)$.

I would also be interested to find the values $r$ and $t$, resp. a functional dependency, where $P_x(r,t)$ is minimal. The red spots on the right already look like as they where lying on a line.

I collected some material of how to get analytical expressions about $P_{x;4,3}(r,t)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477652/19341).