# What does $L(n,\chi_4)$ mean?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I was reading some articles related to Euler sums and the Riemann zeta function, when I came across this definition:

$$
L(n,\chi_4) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^n}
$$

What is this function called and how is it related to the zeta function?

Comment: $\chi_4(n) = (-1)^{(n-1)/2} 1_{2 |n-1}$ is the unique non-trivial Dirichlet character modulo $4$. It is completely multiplicative so that $L(s,\chi_4) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) n^{-s}=\prod_p \frac{1}{1-\chi_4(p) p^{-s}}$. Also $L(s,\chi_4)$ is meromorphic (and even entire) on the whole complex plane, and since $\chi_4$ is its own discrete Fourier transform, it has a functional equation similar to $\zeta(s)$. In one word, a Riemann hypothesis is conjectured for $L(s,\chi_4)$. Those Dirichlet L-functions are also the core of the proof of Dirichlet theorem in arithmetic progressions

Comment: @Pickle You may also be interested by this parallel exposition of the [explicit formulas for $\zeta$ and your Dirichlet L-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269997/two-representations-of-the-prime-counting-function/282848#282848) with a link to a [table of the imaginary parts of the first zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271847/21783).

Comment: @Pickle: your specific series is named a [Dirichlet beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) and allows (for $n$ integer) a [parallel between Euler and Bernoulli numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510363/a-series-related-to-zeta-3).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thanks a lot! I was actually wondering if there was a specific name for the case where the character is $\chi_4$. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @RaymondManzoni The sum in the Dirichlet Beta function goes from 0 to infinity, however here it goes from 1 to infinty...

Comment: Thanks to appreciate my links @Pickle! Should you reference my last link : the OP starts with $n=1$ but with $(2n-1)$ instead of $(2n+1)$ (with a wrong overall sign as commented by anon). Excellent continuation anyway,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That author is writing $\chi_4$ for a certain "character", defined by
$$
  \chi_4(n) = \begin{cases}
1, &n \equiv 1\pmod 4,\\
-1,&n\equiv 3\pmod 4,\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and then
$$
L(s,\chi_4) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_4(n)}{n^s} =
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^s}
$$
is the corresponding "$L$-function" of that character.

The simple connection with the zeta function is that, taking a different character $\chi(n) = 1$ for all $n$, we get
$$
L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s} = \zeta(s)
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, it is not very clear to me how the denominator goes from $n^s$ to $(2k+1)^s$ when applying $\chi_4$ to the numerator...

Comment: $\chi_4(n)=0$ for even $n$, so leave those terms out of the sum.  For odd $n$, write $n = 2k+1$ so $\chi_4(2k+1)=(-1)^k$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!